# SameSite=Strict cookies not sent on reload in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

I can reproduce the issue by following these steps with a website I host:

1. Click a link to the website from any external site
2. Submit an AJAX form that returns a `Set-Cookie` header with the `SameSite=Strict` attribute

   1. At this point I can confirm that the cookie is set by looking in `chrome://settings`
3. Reload the page

On step 3, the cookie is not sent with the request. The devtools network tab shows

> The cookie was blocked because it had the "SameSite=Strict" attribute and the request was made from a different site. This includes top-level navigation requests initiated by other sites.

Is this the correct behavior for `SameSite=Strict` cookies? I understand why the cookie would not be sent with the initial request in step 1 (since it originated from a different site), but I expected that an explicit reload triggered by a user would be considered a same-site request.

[image: samesite cookie blocked]

Comment: I was really surprised by this behavior myself! Did you ever figure out why strict cookies aren't sent on a page reload?